# Distributing pybind11 extension linked to third party libraries

Tags: setuptools, pybind11

I'm working on a pybind11 extension written in C++ but I'm having a hard time understanding how should it be distributed.

The project links to a number of third party libraries (e.g. libpng, glew etc.).

The project builds fine with CMAKE and it generates a .so file. Now I am not sure what is the right way of installing this extension. The extension seems to work, as if I try copy the file into the python lib directories it is picked up (I can import it, and it works correctly). However, this is clearly not the way to go I think.

I also tried the setuptools route (from https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html) by creating a setup.py files like this:

```
import sys

# Available at setup time due to pyproject.toml
from pybind11 import get_cmake_dir
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext
from setuptools import setup
from glob import glob

files = sorted(glob("*.cpp"))

__version__ = "0.0.1"

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("mylib",
        files,
        # Example: passing in the version to the compiled code
        define_macros = [('VERSION_INFO', __version__)],
        ),
]

setup(
    name="mylib",
    version=__version__,
    author="fab",
    author_email="fab@fab",
    url="https://github.com/pybind/python_example",
    description="mylib",
    long_description="",
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    extras_require={"test": "pytest"},
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    zip_safe=False,
    python_requires=">=3.7",
)
```

and now I can build the extension by simply calling

```
pip3 install
```

however it looks like all the links are broken because whenever I try importing the extension in Python I get linkage errors, as if setuptools does not link correctly the extension with the 3rd party libs. For instance errors in linking with libpng as in:

```
>>> import mylib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/fabrizio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mylib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: png_sig_cmp
```

However I have no clue how to add this link info to setuptools, and don't even know if that's possible (it should be the setuptools equivalent of CMAKE's target_link_libraries).
I am really at a loss after weeks of reading documentation, forum threads and failed attempts. If anyone is able to point me in the right way or to clear some of the fog it would be really appreciated!

Thanks!
Fab

Answer (score 1):

```
/home/fabrizio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mylib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: png_sig_cmp
```

This line pretty much says it clearly. Your local shared object file `.so` can't find the `libpng.so` against which it is linked.

You can confirm this by running:

```bash
ldd /home/fabrizio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mylib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

There is no equivalent of `target_link_libraries()` in setuptools. Because **that wouldn't make any sense**. The library is already built and you've already linked it. This is your system more or less telling you that it can't find the libraries it needs. And those most likely need to be installed.

This is also one of the reasons why Linux distributions provide their own package managers and why you should use the `developer` packages provided by said distributions.

So how do you fix this? Well your `.so` file needs to find the other `.so` files against which you linked to understand how this works I will refer you to [this link](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

My main guess is based on the fact that when you manually copy the files it works - That during the build process you **probably** specify the `rpath` to a local directory. Hence what you most likely need to do is specify to your setuptools that it needs to copy those files when installing.

Comment: Hi Milan, thanks for your reply. When I'm talking about target_link_libraries in setuptools I'm talking about using setuptools to actually build the whole library and just install it. In fact, I just found that setuptools allows to specify a list of library to link to using the libraries keyword argument in the Extension object (https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html).

Comment: I think it should be more clearly specified in your post. From what I understood in it, you built it using CMake and then wanted to somehow install it using the setuptools, hence one of the reasons why I suggested an edit with the removal of CMake as a tag. That all being said if I understand you correctly, you've figured this out on your own.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. Actually my goal was try to understand what was the best practice to distribute the package, between: 1) CMAKE + something to install it, 2) setuptools to build and install. I tried both ways, but as I said in the initial post, in 1) I didn't know how to perform the install process (setuptools? actually this is still open), and 2) I had the link problem (now solved).

Comment: @user3093226 you don't hve to apologize for learning / asking questions. In regards to what you ask it's more opinion based than factual. If you were to for example: Ask me, I would say CMake + install as it is more common and CMake is actively supported and developed, but others would disagree. That being said, in the end you managed to fix it and that's all that matters. Good luck with your endeavours!

Comment: but let's say I go for CMAKE + install, which also sounds best to me, what is actually the way to properly install the .so package in Python? (to make it accessible via import mylib).

Comment: @user3093226 Please note that I'm not an expert in `pybind11`, I however did create python bindings for C++ libs in the past. What happens under the hood is that you load the library during runtime and use bindings that you've created for said library (this is some kind of a `.py` file). So as long as LD can find this library (and its dependencies) it should work fine. If you are creating and maintaining a package then the standard path on linux systems is  `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/lib64`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`. However in your case I do not advise to put them here.

Comment: And the main reason for that is related to the fact that you are using custom build dependencies that surely exist in the given distribution, such as `libpng` to name a few. So instead you should chose a custom path and for example specify it via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and for custom dependencies you could utilize the `rpath`. However if it was up to me, I would build this using packages that are available to you from the distributions package manager, and then re-distributing this is a magnitude easier.