# OpenMP + pybind11 (to be compiled with setup.py) on mac and linux

Tags: python, c++, openmp, pybind11

I have a python module that I want to make usable in both macOS and linux, that uses C++ code with OpenMP. I'm having issues on macOS (because apple clang doesn't have OpenMP support, I guess). I have the following `*.cpp` code, [using this example](https://iamsorush.com/posts/pybind11-openmp/):

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
// specific to macOS with libomp installed -- how to generalize?
#include "/usr/local/opt/libomp/include/omp.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

// OpenMP test
int sum_thread_ids(){
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(sum)
    {
        sleep(3);
        #pragma omp critical
        sum += omp_get_thread_num();
    }
    return sum;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(openmp_test, m){
    m.def("get_max_threads", &omp_get_max_threads, "Returns max number of threads");
    m.def("set_num_threads", &omp_set_num_threads, "Set number of threads");
    m.def("sum_thread_ids", &sum_thread_ids, "Adds the id of threads");
}
```

And then `setup.py` has:

```
import os
from glob import glob
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import module_name

cxx_std = int(os.environ.get("CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD", "20"))

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("openmp_test", sorted(glob("src/*.cpp")), cxx_std=cxx_std)
]

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['pybind11'],
    python_requires='>=3.10',
    ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

I install within the module dir that contains `setup.py` by:

```
pip install .
```

It compiles without errors. However, when I try to use it in python, I get:

```
>>>import openmp_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/.../.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openmp_test.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_omp_get_max_threads'
```

What am I missing? And how can I make this usable on both macOS and linux?

Comment: Sounds like your `openmp_test.cpython-311-darwin.so` doesn't link with `libomp.so`

Comment: @pptaszni that makes sense -- how would I go about linking it?

Comment: I know how to [build it with CMake](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-with-cmake) but no clue about setuptools. If you `ldd openmp_test.cpython-311-darwin.so` you can confirm it doesn't have the correct dependencies, right? Because there is also `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it doesn't seem to be your case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098934/distributing-pybind11-extension-linked-to-third-party-libraries - this is the same issue you are having, but it doesn't seem to be resolved.

Comment: BTW, this `#include "/usr/local/opt/libomp/include/omp.h"` looks like some dirty hack. Normally that path should be passed to the compiler as include directory.

Comment: @pptaszni I guess I could switch to CMake. I just need to learn how that works, although, my initial understanding is that I have to worry about specifically where everything goes in site-packages.

It seems like `ldd` does not exist on macOS anymore :/.

I agree with the include statement -- I could not find a better answer. It seems to be a macos issue...